# Bootstrap Multilevel Dropdown Menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using these css rule for multi level dropdown menu as below:

```
/*Multilevel Dropdown*/
/**
* Bootstrap 2.0 dropdown multi-level menu enabler
* Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns
*/
/* overrides */
.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li ul {
display:block; 
position:absolute; 
left:100%;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}

.nav li.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu ul {
display: none;
float:right;
position: relative;
top: auto;
margin-top: -30px;
}
```

and HTML as this:

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="url dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Dropdown<i class="icon-chevron-down"></i></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Level1</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">

            <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>

            <li><a href="#">Level2</a></li>                                                              
        </ul>
      </li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

It works perfectly for Chrome and Firefo however 2nd or more levels doesn't appear on IE9 when hovering on the 1st level. What can be the issue ?

Comment: I don't understand your code, can you post a working version over at http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: By the way, you're not adding the `:hover` states in your css.

Comment: There's no multi level menus in twitter's bootstrap. I was looking for that thing too. Couldn't find anything on the interwebs, so I wrote my own. Here's the github repo: [Multi-Menu](https://github.com/pwarelis/Multi-Menu) Enjoy!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Multilevel Dropdown Menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758587/twitter-bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu)