# Multi-level menu bootstrap

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap, navigation

Does anyone know how I can create a multi-level navigation bar using either Bootstrap or jQuery mobile, that works correctly on mobile devices (particularly iPad and iPhone) up to the second sub-menu level?

I found this question with a suggestion based on standard Bootstrap: [Twitter Bootstrap Multilevel Dropdown Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758587/twitter-bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu)

But it still does not work on the iPad. You can not tap any of the "Second level link" items (at least not on my client's iPad - I don't own one).

I also looked into jQuery Mobile, and cannot find a solution for JQM either. Is this a plague with the iPad that does not have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All research indicated that this can not be done with bootstrap. I have decided to develop a custom JavaScript/jQuery menu myself and this works well.