# Twitter Bootstrap and menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i used twitter bootstrap for responsive websites. Its great tool. I have  a problem on current websites. I need three level dropdown menu so like main nav -> sub item -> sub item.

similar to http://www.bestbuy.com/ when u hover on product.
Is that possible on twitter bootstrap

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. Using [the example on the bootstrap site](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns) as a basis, add a submenu to the existing submenu.

Like this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
        <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Second level link</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Even More options</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Third level link</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Third level link</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Third level link</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Third level link</a></li>
                    <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Third level link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

use the `class="dropdown-menu sub-menu"` to do this. any level of nesting is possible.
[sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/seelan/2Smgv/2442/)

credits: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758587/twitter-bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu) by [Andres Ilich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/680398/andres-ilich)