# Keep-bootstrap-3-dropdown-open-when-clicked

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need help achieving the same navigation as below link.

It has my code along with clients requirement. And I'm using Bootstrap 3

```
Bootstrap Dropdowns - dropdown.js
```

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nepdud/wUn4E/)

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/wUn4E/1/)

You need to make just one change:

Instead of listening to `hide.bs.dropdown` event for only `.dropdown.active`
apply the event handler to `.dropdown`.

Basically, change:

`$(".dropdown.active").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {`

to:

`$(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {`

---

**EDIT:**
In order to override the default dropdown behavior, you'll need to ignore the `active` state since more than one `li` element can remain expanded and you'll need to toggle visibility yourself.

[**Here's the updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/srvikram13/wUn4E/5/)

**Code:**

```
$(function(){

    //  Handle show/hide toggle yourself
    $(".dropdown").on("click",function(e) {
        if($(e.currentTarget).hasClass("open"))
            $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("open",false);
        else 
            $(e.currentTarget).toggleClass("open",true);
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
    });

    //  suppressing default bahavior
    $(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown", doNothing);            
    $(".dropdown").on("show.bs.dropdown", doNothing);

    function doNothing(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried it and updated jsfiddle. The problem is its making everything active. Can you help me with the same?

Comment: Fix it: Uncaught ReferenceError: e is not defined. Just change "function doNothing(e) {"

Comment: Thank you  for this, actually i used multilevel dropdown for eCommerce mega menu, in mobile for default `hide.bs.dropdown` behavior caused page to scroll up so we want to keep the dropdown open if once opened and also allow user  to close when the dropdown itself is clicked. Initially i tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982308/bootstrap3-keep-the-dropdown-menu-open-after-click-on-the-item) but Your answer helped.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its the right way but i did

```
$(function(){
  $('.nav').find('li.dropdown.active').addClass('open');
  $(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 
        return false;
   });
  $('.navbar-main li').on('click', function (){
    var me = $(this);
    $('.navbar-main li').removeClass('open');
    $(this).addClass('open');
  });
});
```

and its working fine :)