# BootStrap3 keep the dropdown menu open after click on the item

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0, with its excellent drop-down menu.

If I click outside of the drop-down menu the menu will disappear, and that is ok.

But when I click on a drop-down menu item, the menu disappears. I do not want this to happen, and there is no option to control the toggle behavior. I want the menu to remain open after clicking on one of the items, like the Facebook notification menu.

I think I have to modify the Bootstrap source, which I don't really want to do. So before I touch the source, I want to know is there any good workaround? If not, how should I change the source for minimum impact on Bootstrap?

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keep Bootstrap Dropdown Open When Clicked Off](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here is one way to keep the dropdown open after click...

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
    return false;
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/116350

Another option is to handle the click event like this..

```
$('#myDropdown .dropdown-menu').on({
    "click":function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/116581

Comment: Thanks so much, but when I tried, the menu will keep open even click out side the menu... and the demo link is broken

Comment: What happens when you try the demo link? How is it broken?

Comment: oh, few hours ago, it said some error happened. now it's working. but the problem remain.

Comment: Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

Comment: The second option works great for click events, anythoughts on touch? I've tried touchstart, and touch with out luck on either.

Comment: The first option works, but on mobile now I have to click twice before the link is activated. The second option doesn't work on mobile, tried to use touch and touchstart in this option but without success. Any suggestions?

Comment: This works and **keeps the drop down always open** in multilevel drop down, but **what if user wants to close the drop down** or you probably want to allow it to close when the dropdown itself is clicked ? Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694010/keep-bootstrap-3-dropdown-open-when-clicked) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off), hope helps someone.

Comment: for bootstrap 4, it helped me to change the jq class selector from .dropdown-menu  to .dropdown-item
 ie: `#myDropdown .dropdown-item`

Answer (score 6):

The accepted answer is very helpful. I want to provide another perspective - when a drop down menu should stay open when only certain items are clicked.

```
// A utility for keeping a Bootstrap drop down menu open after a link is
// clicked
//
// Usage:
//
//   <div class="dropdown">
//     <a href="" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
//       Dropdown trigger <span class="caret"></span>
//     </a>
//
//     <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
//       <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
//       <li><a href="" keep-menu-open="true">Delete</a></li>
//     </ul>
//  </div>

$(".dropdown .dropdown-menu a").on("click", function(e) {
  var keepMenuOpen = $(this).data("keep-menu-open"),
      $dropdown = $(this).parents(".dropdown");

  $dropdown.data("keep-menu-open", keepMenuOpen);
});

$(".dropdown").on("hide.bs.dropdown", function(e) {
  var keepMenuOpen = $(this).data("keep-menu-open");

  $(this).removeData("keep-menu-open");

  return keepMenuOpen !== true;
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In vanilla JS

```
document.getElementById('myDropdown').addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
```