# Bootstrap MultiSelect Stay Open

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

Is there any option to stay open the multi select dropdown.

I have found two ways to stay open (but its fails),

```
1) $('#multi_ Div').addClass('open');
2) $("#multi_ .dropdown-toggle").click();
```

But dropdown will close when we click on any other field on page.

here is the [sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/r0kbch7u/3/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982308/bootstrap3-keep-the-dropdown-menu-open-after-click-on-the-item

Comment: Its not working, I have to click first time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BootStrap3 keep the dropdown menu open after click on the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21982308/bootstrap3-keep-the-dropdown-menu-open-after-click-on-the-item)

Answer (score 2):

I found the way to stay open the multi select dropdown

Just call this line of code after initial the multi select dropdown

```
$('#multi_').parent().find('ul').attr('style','display:block;');
```

I am thinking, why there is not any option to do this by setting up initial time.

http://jsfiddle.net/r0kbch7u/47/

Comment: The issue was already discussed here: https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/issues/426