# Toggle Bootstrap dropdown by click on the link in modal

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

When a form submitted the modal box appears. This box contains a text with a link. Click on this link should close this box and toggle dropdown (auth form). The problem is that I can't handle toggling the dropdown by clicking this link.

Here is the code of click-handler of this link

```
$(function() {
    $('#open_auth_form').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#participate_modal').modal('hide');
        $('#auth_link').dropdown('toggle');
    });
});
```

Why doesn't it work? I tried also to move dropdown toggling inside the 'hide.bs.modal', tried .trigger('click'). Nothing helped. But simple running

```
$('#auth_link').dropdown('toggle');
```

from console works well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this stack overflow question on [How to open Bootstrap dropdown programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842903/how-to-open-bootstrap-dropdown-programmatically). There are a number of solutions you can try such as:

Triggering the click.bs.dropdown event:

`$('#dropdown').trigger('click.bs.dropdown');`

Or manually adding/removing the classes:

```
$('.dropdown').addClass('open'); // Opens the dropdown
$('.dropdown').removeClass('open'); // Closes it
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was enough to add 
    e.stopPropagation();