# how to create a dropdown passengers count form?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

Can someone help me out here on how to add passengers count dropdown form like on the image below. i have been searching all over but cannot seem to find any demo or help.

[image: the red marked section]

thanks for your help

Comment: Kinda like this ? https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/4no2R

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen yes but this one by default is pop open and once selected unable to open the dropdown after selection. else it was almost the same.

Comment: Abigail yes, but then you can just modify it a bit.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen I wish i knew javascript :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution using pure HTML, CSS, and jQuery. For a Bootstrap-specific answer, [How use input field as toggle for bootstrap 4 dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625487/how-use-input-field-as-toggle-for-bootstrap-4-dropdown) may help.

Moving on.

You should create a normal number type form and add a `disabled` attribute in the `input` tag so that no cursor appears when you click the form (`<input type="number" disabled>`). Then, just create a dropdown menu (probably a `<div>` with an absolute position right under the input) with a classname of your choice (assuming in this answer that you choose `.passengerInput` as the classname).

You can hide the dropdown by default using the `$(".passengerInputDropdown").hide()` method in the body of your JS.

Then, when you click the form, using the `$(".passengerInput").toggle()` method, do something to the effect of:

```
$(".passengerInput").on("click", () => {
    $(".passengerInputDropdown").toggle();
})
```

Let me know if this helps!