# Check the status of Bootstraps of dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to use jQuery to open and close the dropdown. I checked this question, but it is about open only.
[How to open Bootstrap dropdown programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842903/how-to-open-bootstrap-dropdown-programmatically)
I found these two command to open it and close it.

```
$('.dropdown-menu').show();
$('.dropdown-menu').close();
```

However, how can I know the current status of the dropdown? I want click to close if it is open, and click to open if it is close.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the event :

```
// var to be visible in the global scope

var status = false; // default hidden 

$('#myDropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', () => status = false)

$('#myDropdown').on('shown.bs.dropdown', () => status = true)
```

Later you can check for the `status` value;

Comment: I don't want to introduce new variables. Is it possible to just check the status?

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#dropdowns-methods), there is one method `toggle` to do both open and close. As the name suggests, it basically "toggles" between the states.

You use it like:

```
$('#example').dropdown('toggle');
```

But I recommend you upgrade to use [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/), because this adds loads of new functionality including several new [methods](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#methods) for `dropdown`.

Using the new methods, you can separate the two actions:

```
$('#example').dropdown('show');
$('#example').dropdown('hide');
```

---

To determine the current state in either version, you can utilise the `aria-expanded` attribute on the dropdown `<a>` toggle. This attribute changes it's boolean value depending on whether it's open or closed.

You can create an `if` statement check, something like:

```js
if($("#example .dropdown-toggle[aria-expanded='true'") {
   // dropdown open, so we can close it now.
}
```