# bootstrap 2.x dropdown hide when click outside

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

bootstrap 2.x dropdown hide when click outside wants to keep open the dropdown. following is the sample html.

```
<ul class="pull-left">
    <li class="dropdown open" id="stayOpen"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-inverse dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Notes"><i class="icon-list icon-white" role="button"></i></a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
       <li><h5>Dropdown options</h5></li>
      </ul>
   </li>    
</ul>
```

Comment: Please create an example of your problem with bootply (http://www.bootply.com/) and ask your question more detailed. Right now I don't understand your question.

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off

Comment: @user3127896 not a duplicate given link solution for bootstrap 3.0 and i need a same solution in bootstrap 2.x. thanks,