# jQuery handling of click event on checkbox nested inside <li> and <a> elements while leaving parent <ul> open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

This seems like a simple issue but it is frustrating me. I want to be able to click multiple items in a dropdown list that contains checkboxes without collapsing the list. I've tried a variety of event handlers on the ul, li, and a elements with no luck. These include e.preventDefault(), e.stopPropogation(), and preventing the closing of the ul through the 'hide.bs.dropdown' event as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off) answer.

My list items:

```
<li class="serviceListItem">
  <a class="serviceListItemLink">
    <input class="checkService" type="checkbox" value="">
  </a>
</li>
```

and my current set of event handlers. I've tried most combinations of these.

```
$('#serviceDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  return false;
});

$('.serviceListItemLink').click(function(e) {
  console.log('you clicked a service');
  e.stopPropogation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
$('.serviceListItem').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropogation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I should add my UL has the #servicesDropdown ID. Thanks for all your help in advance SO.

Comment: Can you share a jsfiddle for the issue?

Comment: I will if the issue persists after I check out [bootstrap dropdown enhancements](https://github.com/behigh/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement)

Comment: It turns out, though I was spelling propagation wring, that the 'noclose' class from the dropdown enhancements was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that the code you have tried? In that case, you have misspelled "propagation".

It should be:

```
e.stopPropagation();
```

...and not:

```
e.stopPropogation();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, but using e.stopPropogation() on just the checkbox item does nothing. Perhaps this is because three elements are being clicked when you click a checkbox: the a, li, and input. I have tried using e.stopPropogation on all of these elements together but to no avail.