# How to keep menu stay opening after clicking menu item in tinymce

Tags: tinymce

I want to keep the menu opening after clicking the items with menubutton.

I just read all document about tinymce 5 but can't find a useful answer or 
related document.

Is any method to keep the menu opening even user click the items just like below url?

[Keeping the dropdown open after selecting dropdown element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30237189/keeping-the-dropdown-open-after-selecting-dropdown-element)

Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just resolve my problem by modifying the theme.min.js file

just change

function(t){n(ey(t,Kp.CLOSE_ON_EXECUTE,e))}

to

function(t){n(ey(t,1,e))}

It works!

but I think it affect all meunbutton control's behavior , just be careful to modify it.