# Bootstrap - dropdown menu close on click in Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working with Bootstrap and date picker. I added a datepicker in boostrap dowpdown. When selecting the date the dropdown closes automatically. Refer the image for more info:

[image]
**Action 1:** Click the dropdown button, We see the dropdown list.
**Action 2:** When clicking on the fiel. I will dynamically add datepicker.
**After the action 3:** When selecting on the Date. The Dropdown is getting close so The user is back to Action 1.

What i am trying to do is After the user click the Date. The dropdown should not close.

I am using the following code to prevent the click which workes on the table inside the dropdown but not with the date picker.

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('keep-open-on-click')) { e.stopPropagation(); }
        });
```

Can some one help me to prevent the dropdown close.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-bell"></span><span class="notification" id="notification_count">11</span>
                    </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu keep-open-on-click">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: The datepicker will be added dynamically when the user clicks on the table to end it the date. So is that the problem?

Comment: I am not worried about the datepicker closing, My drop down menu gets closing after i select the date. @JB06

Comment: Is it because the click is passing through the datepicker causing the next section behind it to open? Or does it just close?

Comment: It just close the dropdown.. When i open again.. we see the date was selected in the editbox.

Comment: The datepicker library must use the same class that's assigned to your dropdown to close the datepicker. Try turning off autoclose in the datepicker and see if it still happens.

Comment: I tried that too but no use.. @JB06

Comment: Your design could be too ambitious.  What about using a modal popup to host your accordion panel instead?

Comment: That was the initial though but dropdown looked good. :) @shanabus

Comment: @shanabus u changed my mind.. now i worked with modal.. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not able to solve this issue so I changed my solution from drop-down to Modal.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#NModal"><span class="icon16 icomoon-icon-bell"></span><span class="notification" id="notification_count">11</span>
                    </a>
<div id="NModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" style="min-width: 650px;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<!-- My Code -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This one was very troublesome. I also have a couple of datepickers located within some Bootstrap drop-down menus. I solved this using two ways.

The first uses jQuery to stop the event from bubbling up one time when the DatePicker is clicked

```
$('.yourDatePicker').on('hide', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).closest('.yourDropDown').one('hide.bs.dropdown', function(ev) {
       return false;
   });
});
```

The other, more permant solution was to change the datepicker.js file itself. If you crack it open you will find code that looks like this

```
click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th'),
            year, month, day;
        if (target.length === 1){
            switch (target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()){
...ect...
```

If you add a e.stopPropagation() function to this area, like this

```
click: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation(); // <-- add this
        var target = $(e.target).closest('span, td, th'),
            year, month, day;
        if (target.length === 1){
            switch (target[0].nodeName.toLowerCase()){
```

your datepickers will stop interfering with your other DOM elements, though this solution is more widespread, and I would test to make sure it doesn't impact other areas in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should work BUT

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('keep-open-on-click')) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    });
```

This is looking for the class('keep-open-on') on the datepicker, not the dropdown. You need to find it in the parent I believe.

```
$(document).on('click', '.datepicker', function(e) {
        if ($(this).parents().find('keep-open-on-click')) { e.stopPropagation(); }
    });
```

Should work.

Comment: The problem is not with the date picker can u see the question?

Comment: Yes but I did not understand it, why don't you make a pen for it so we can help you better there buddy.

Comment: Are you talking about the dropdown of the accordion widget?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
$(document).on('click', '.dropdown-menu', function(e) {
            if ($(this).hasClass('keep-open-on-click')) {   
             e.hide(); 
            }
        });
```

Comment: I tried ur code and it just activates other unwanted functions. But the problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to capture the `change` event of the datepicker selection and prevent the default actions from finishing.  Try this:

```
$('#your-datepicker-input').datepicker({
}).on('change', function(e) {
    console.log("changed");
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Example here: https://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/a5f82nsy/

**Update 1**

Without your code for an example, I'm guessing its something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/shanabus/oghgwa5j/1/ - here we have a dropdown with a `datepicker` inside of it.  When I add code so that clicking that table cell turns it into an input with a datepicker, it hijacks the functionality of the dropdown - probably because its a dropdown within a dropdown.

Perhaps you will need a better UI design to handle this type of scenario.  A datepicker dropdown inside of a table, inside of an accordion panel, inside of a dropdown might be as tricky to use as it is to code.

**Update 2**

Here is a great answer on how to better control the dropdown in basic use cases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19797577/88732

Comment: U dont understand. My problem is the dropdown is getting close not with the datepicker. I used ur code still not working..

Comment: Help us understand. Lots of answers here and none of them work? Perhaps your question is not clear. Post some code, that would help.

Comment: I have added details Actions can u pls check it.