# Prevent bootstrap dropdown closing when clicked anywhere else other than the menu item itself

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need the submenu to be opened when its child is active (as in when the user is on that page). Managed to do so already by this:

```
// To open active submenu on load
jQuery('.keep-open').find('.current-menu-item').closest('.current-menu-parent').children('.dropdown-toggle').trigger('click');
```

But upon clicking anywhere, the menu closes. It needs to stay opened unless it's specifically clicked. Only managed to prevent it from closing when clicked outside using this:

```
// To prevent submenu from being closed on outside click
jQuery('.current-menu-parent').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
  return false;
});
```

But of course, this seems prevents it from closing too even when the menu itself is clicked. How can I specify it to close only when that menu item is clicked?

Closest reference I found but was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25089297/twitter-bootstrap-avoid-dropdown-menu-close-on-click-inside) but so far still can't get a hold of how to do it. This is on a WordPress site menu via `wp_bootstrap_navwalker`.

**[Jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/suika/j7fths9w/2/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to close only when that menu is clicked just add this code

```
// Hide dropdown when click menu
jQuery('.current-menu-parent').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeOut();
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/j7fths9w/7/)

Or you want to show menu item again when that menu is clicked:

```
// toggle dropdown when click menu
jQuery('.current-menu-parent').bind('click', function() {
        $(this).find('ul').fadeToggle();
});
```

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/j7fths9w/6/)

Comment: Thank you! Used `.toggle()` instead though to preserve the original behaviour.