# Avoid dropdown close on clicking outside

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

Avoid dropdown closing by clicking outside.Show and hide dropdown while clicking only on button. Heres the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2fgp0Lw6/1/).

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown Example
  <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 Dropdown eventing is slightly different than Bootstrap 3, therefore the [suggested duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off) (and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055541/)) will *not* work to prevent the dropdown from closing on an outside click.

For **Bootstrap 4**, [look for the `clickEvent`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#events), and when found in the `hide` event, prevent the default close behavior. This dropdown will only close when the **button** is clicked.

```
$('#myDD').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    if (e.clickEvent) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
})
```

[Demo](https://www.codeply.com/go/Ai786lQzd8)

---

In some cases, you may want the Dropdown to close when the **button *or* menu** is clicked. In this case you can examine the clickEvent target. For example, look for the 'nav-link' class.

```
$('#myDD').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function (e) {
    if (e.clickEvent && e.clickEvent.target.className!="nav-link") {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

[Demo 2](https://www.codeply.com/go/PIRxxHg1ZE)

Comment: Any way to make it close when you click a menu item? OP didn't specify, but could be useful.

Comment: I'm sure there is, but I didn't provide that answer since OP said *"Show and hide dropdown while clicking only on button"*. I will update the answer with another option.

Comment: Why I cant able to achieve it in this https://jsfiddle.net/Ld46q0za/1/ @Zim

Comment: This is incorrect, hide.bs.dropdown does not have clickEvent property

Comment: Yes, it does have a clickEvent property [as explained in the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/dropdowns/#events), but "only when the original event type is click"

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to make your own menu-toggling click event instead of using the one bootstrap provides and then attempting to override things

### Bootstrap 3

```js
var $ddlBtn = $("#my-custom-ddl");
$ddlBtn.on("click", function(){
  var expanded = /true/i.test($ddlBtn.attr("aria-expanded"));
  $ddlBtn
    .attr("aria-expanded", !expanded)
    .parent().toggleClass("open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="my-custom-ddl" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

### Bootstrap 4

```js
var $ddlBtn = $("#my-custom-ddl");
$ddlBtn.on("click", function(){
  var expanded = /true/i.test($ddlBtn.attr("aria-expanded"));
  $ddlBtn
    .attr("aria-expanded", !expanded)
    .siblings(".dropdown-menu").toggleClass("show")
    .parent().toggleClass("show");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="my-custom-ddl" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown Example
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="my-custom-ddl">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Javascript</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes probably true, but the original question use bootstrap 3 CSS and never mentioned which version to use.

Comment: ok, updated to include a working example for both 3 & 4 now, also with `aria-*` attribute support