# Keeping the dropdown open after selecting dropdown element bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

I have this dropdown on my side-nav and want it to stay open when one dropdown element is clicked/accessed. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<li class="nav-item">

<a class="nav-link {{ ($prefix == 'admin/category' || $prefix == 'admin/subCategory') ? 'activeSideNavParent' : '' }}" href="" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="icon icon-shape icon-sm border-radius-md text-center me-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <i class="ni ni-ungroup text-primary text-sm opacity-10"></i>
    </div>
    <span class="nav-link-text ms-1">Categories</span>
</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu mt-0">

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ ($prefix == 'admin/category') ? 'btn activeSideNav' : '' }}" href="{{ route('admin.category.index') }}">
            <div class="icon icon-shape icon-sm border-radius-md text-center me-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <i class="ni ni-ungroup text-primary text-sm opacity-10"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="nav-link-text ms-1">Category</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link {{ ($prefix == 'admin/subCategory') ? 'btn activeSideNav' : '' }}" href="{{ route('admin.subCategory.index') }}">
            <div class="icon border-radius-md text-center me-2 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center sideNavButton">
                <i class="ni ni-align-center text-primary text-sm opacity-10"></i>
            </div>
            <span class="nav-link-text ms-1">Sub Category</span>
        </a>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I tried solving this using the following solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19740121/keep-bootstrap-dropdown-open-when-clicked-off) answer but couldn't reach the expected outcome.\

```
$('#myDropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
return false;
```

});

Comment: please modify the livedemo js fiddle of the linked answer and include a reproducible example in the OP

Comment: is OK that you have any effect, cause you have any "#myDropdown" button