# How to achieve submenus

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I am coding the following in Bootstrap 3.0 and MVC 5. I am trying to get Submenus to work. I referenced [navbar documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) but I can't get the Billing and Payment structure to be a sub dropdown menu with this structure:

```
Account Info
    License Details
    Billing and Payment
       Invoices
       Payments
       Billing
    Users
       User Settings
```

Here is my HTML. I need to replace the anchor tag on Billing Payment. What do I put in its place?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Free Trial Setup", "Trial", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account Info</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("License Details", "License", "Home" )</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu"></li>
                                <a href="#">Billing and Payment</a>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Invoices", "Invoices", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payments", "Payments", "Home")</li>
                                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Billing Information", "Billing", "Home")</li>
                            </ul>
                            <li>User Settings</li>
                        </ul>

                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/2858/) with an example of a nested submenu in BS3.  It comes from the Updated answer in this post from [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758587/twitter-bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu).  Hope that helps.

Comment: I listed the wrong version of Bootstrap -- that example is BS2.

Comment: There is no dropdown-submenu in BS3. I'll update my code above as I still can't get it working right.

Comment: Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18023493/bootstrap-3-dropdown-sub-menu-missing)?  In some ways, not very encouraging -- but a workaround is presented.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the solution mentioned in [snippet](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/multi-level-dropdown-menu-bs3) you have to do the following:

1. Add following to your **Site.css** file

   ```
   .dropdown-submenu {
   position: relative; 
   }

   .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu {
       top: 0;
       left: 100%;
       margin-top: -6px;
       margin-left: -1px;
       -webkit-border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
       -moz-border-radius: 0 6px 6px;
       border-radius: 0 6px 6px 6px;
   }

   .dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
       display: block;
   }

   .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
       display: block;
       content: " ";
       float: right;
       width: 0;
       height: 0;
       border-color: transparent;
       border-style: solid;
       border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
       border-left-color: #ccc;
       margin-top: 5px;
       margin-right: -10px;
   }

   .dropdown-submenu:hover > a:after {
       border-left-color: #fff;
   }

   .dropdown-submenu.pull-left {
       float: none;
   }

       .dropdown-submenu.pull-left > .dropdown-menu {
           left: -100%;
           margin-left: 10px;
           -webkit-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
           -moz-border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
           border-radius: 6px 0 6px 6px;
       }
   ```

then change your code in the **_Layout.cshtml** to be:

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Free Trial Setup", "Trial", "Home")</li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account Info</a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-level" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                            <li>@Html.ActionLink("License Details", "License", "Home")</li>
                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                <a tabindex="-1" href="#">Billing and Payment</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Invoices", "Invoices", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Payments", "Payments", "Home")</li>
                                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Billing Information", "Billing", "Home")</li>
                                    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                        <a href="#">Users</a>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a href="#">User Settings</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                @Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
            </div>
```