# Make bootstrap drop down buttons cascading

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have added two drop down boxes on my webpage like below, but I want to make them cascading and then pass the value of the drop down button to a function.

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle">Success <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
</div><!-- /btn-group -->
<div class="btn-group">
   <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle">Info <span class="caret"></span></button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Another action</a></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Something else here</a></li>
         <li class="divider"></li>
         <li><a href="#" onClick="return false;">Separated link</a></li>
      </ul>
</div><!-- /btn-group -->
```

Comment: What do you mean by cascading? I also suggest you to build a bootply and add your code (include your js functions).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9773450/3917754 Check this answer of @Andres Ilich 
I think it's what you want

Comment: thanks for the link... but what I want is suppose a user select a country from the first drop down .. then all the states related to the selected country should be populated in the second drop down

Comment: You would need an array that would pertain to the country selected. After that it is fairly easy.

Comment: @Press Not necessarily, you could also use Enumerations to accomplish the task. Simply map the country enum to the state enum.

Comment: can you please provide me some code... I am pretty new to this..

Comment: @KyleT I've actually never used enums in Javascript.

Comment: @Press Have a look at this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287903/enums-in-javascript. They are very similar to how you have used arrays in your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As KyleT mentioned in the comments you could accomplish with enum in place of arrays. However as a comfort pick I'll be using an array. **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9tphbve/1/)**

```js
var states = [
    "Kansas",
    "Oklahoma",
    "Texas"    
];

$('.dropdown-menu > li > a').click(function() {
    yourFunction(this.text);
});

function yourFunction(val) {
        
    if ( val === "Action" ) {
        $('#states').html('');
        for ( var i in states ) {
            $('#states').append("<li><a href='#'>" + states[i] + "</a></li>");
        }
    }
    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle">Success <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /btn-group -->
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle">Info <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="states">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>
    </li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /btn-group -->
```