# Trouble with custom boostrap dropdown list

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dropdownbox

[I have a fiddle that doesn't work](http://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/a5n64pp6/1/)

I am trying to make a "dropdown" type effect with a list of inputs and a button for some functionality.  Basically, there is a table, and then a list of 6 inputs that can filter the results on this table.  I have the view complete and working correctly (although I stripped out the functionality for my fiddle).

I understand that I need to use a general layout of

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <div>
          <input/>
      <div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div>
          <input/>
      </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Because a `<div>` must not go directly inside a `<ul>`

What am I doing wrong?

[link to what i want to see after my dropdown is clicked](http://jsfiddle.net/jfakey/3we26e82/)

Comment: The dropdown will appear on top of the other content that's why it only makes sense to have it directly after the trigger, I think what you want to do is just add a hidden div and when the button is clicked you show it (toggle class hide). Or maybe have a look into bootstrap collapse.

Comment: @maraca I do like what you are doing here, however the purpose here is to have the dropdown menu overlay the content, not push the content down the page.  I think this makes doing a `show`/`hide` not practical here, and I'd prefer to use no javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/a5n64pp6/2/)?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Action</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <!-- dropdown content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

of course, you can set `dropdown-menu`'s width to whatever you desire.

Comment: I don't know why I felt that I needed to use a `<ul>` in my dropdown, this makes the most sense

Comment: when I click on the select list within the dropdown on your fiddle the dropdown closes

Comment: @USER_8675309 looks like you might need to use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758587/twitter-bootstrap-multilevel-dropdown-menu

Answer (score 1):

This might help.

```css
.menu-large {
  position: static !important;
  text-align: center;
}
.megamenu {
  padding: 20px 0px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="http://placehold.it/15x15/f00" />
  </a>
  <a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="#">
    <img alt="Brand" src="http://placehold.it/15x15/f00" />
  </a>

  <div class="navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown menu-large"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Stuff <span class="caret"></span></a>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu megamenu">
          <li>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <form>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Input" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input2" placeholder="Input" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input3" placeholder="Input" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="input4" placeholder="Input" />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <select class="form-control">
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm-update btn-primary ">UPDATE</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm-x btn-default transparent glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: the inputs and select lists should be inside the dropdown here

Comment: this is good -- I've got mine working as well thanks to all of you.  +1 for updating it even after I accepted the answer